# ios: How to restart app when it terminated in background?

Tags: ios, background, gps, location

I write app (for use in auto) which works in background and use gps (startUpdatingLocations).
Of'cource I know about bgModes in plist and battery drain.
And I need exactly gps - with high accuracy.

Application works normally until the other gps-app not goes to foreground.
After some time, since user open another navigation program the iOs system terminate my program.
I can just notify user "Sorry, but os decide to kill my application. Restart it again".
But it's not good.

So, is it a way to restart program (in background)???

Absolutely standard code. Nothing special

```
class "gps"
-(id)init
{
.....
    locMan = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locMan.delegate=self;
    locMan.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locMan.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
.....   
}

-(void)start
{
..............
    if(sysVer>=8.0)
    {
        [locMan requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    [locMan startUpdatingLocation];
    if(sysVer>=6)
    {
        locMan.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
    }
............
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    ... processing
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   ... processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the significant change notification to cause your app to be restarted after it is killed.

From [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> If you leave the significant-change location service running and your iOS app is subsequently suspended or terminated, the service automatically wakes up your app when new location data arrives. At wake-up time, the app is put into the background and you are given a small amount of time (around 10 seconds) to manually restart location services and process the location data.